# How to set bookmark anchor so \section- and \section*-bookmark behaves the same

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, bookmarks, book-design

If I make a `\section` and `\section*` bookmark, the anchor points to the two sections in a different place. A small vertical space is added to `\section*` (see `.png`-files). How can I make sure the anchor is placed at the same place?

I need this solution since I would like to make a *List of Appendices*, where the entries only need to be showned in `LoA` and not `ToC`, but I still need the section numbers in the text and `LoA`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{bookmark}
\hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered=true}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter one}

References here:

ref: \ref{chap2} (chapter)

ref: \ref{chap2sec1} (section)

ref: \ref{chap2sec2} (star-section)

\chapter{Chapter two}\label{chap2}

...(contents of chapter 2)...

\section{Sec one}\label{chap2sec1}

...(contents of chapter 2 - section 1)...

\refstepcounter{section}
\section*{\thesection{}{\quad}Sec two}\label{chap2sec2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}Sec two}

...(contents of chapter 2 - section 2)...

\end{document}
```

[image: Normal section bookmark (\section)]
[image: Star-section bookmark (\section*)]

**EDIT (1):** I have added a red box to show the wrong bookmark anchor for `\section*`. The spacing between sections are correct it's only the anchor settings that's wrong.

Comment: Could you please draw over the images which is that added space?

Comment: I have added a red box now. Please see edit comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the way `\section` works and make `\section*` act the same way `\section` does, only with some minor modifications:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{bookmark}
\hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered=true}

\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname\space}% Just for this example
\let\oldsection\section
\let\oldaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {{% \section*
      \renewcommand{\refstepcounter}[1]{\phantomsection}% Gobble counter stepping
      \renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{}% Gobble section number formatting
      \renewcommand{\addcontentsline}[3]{\oldaddcontentsline{toc}{section}{#3}}% Next entry _will_ be a section
      \oldsection{#3}% \section*[.]{..}
    }}{% \section
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\oldsection{#3}}% \section{..}
        {\oldsection[#2]{#3}}% \section[.]{..}
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter one}

References here:

ref: \ref{chap2} (chapter)

ref: \ref{chap2sec1} (section)

ref: \ref{chap2sec2} (star-section)

\chapter{Chapter two}\label{chap2}

...(contents of chapter 2)...

\section{Sec one}\label{chap2sec1}

...(contents of chapter 2 - section 1)...

\stepcounter{section}%
\section*{\thesection{} Sec two}\label{chap2sec2}

...(contents of chapter 2 - section 2)...

\end{document}
```

[`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) is used to easily capture the arguments typically managed by `\section` (starred-version, optional and mandatory arguments).

When `\section*` is called, we update three things which are typical for `\section*`:

1. The counter stepping `\refstepcounter` is made into a no-op;
2. The section counter formatting macro `\@seccntformat` is converted into a no-op;
3. The contents-related writing is updated to be specific to the input, thereby avoiding a possible `\numberline` printing.

Since `\section` and `\section*` now use the same procedure for printing the header (namely `\@sect`, internally), the output hyperlinks jump to the same vertical location.

Your example is slightly contrived as it includes a manual `\refstepcounter` as part of Section 2.2. However, I don't see any problems with the hyperlink jumps using the updated version of `\section` defined above.